# Datatables Refresh Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatable

I've been troubleshooting this issue to the point of frustration, so I have made my way back to Stackoverflow. I am very much a beginner so bear with me, and I thank you for any help ahead of time.

I am using Datatables with my rails application and I am trying to get the table to update after I add a row to the database. I followed the tutorial at rails-casts, found here: [Rails-casts: JQuery and Ajax](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised), to get to where I am currently.

I have been successful in providing a link on the page that is replaced by a form on click. The form submits data to the database successfully, and the form is then replaced by the original link (just like in the rails-cast tutorial). The only problem I am running into is trying to get the table to refresh without the whole page refreshing.

I currently don't get any errors. I have also tried the Datatables method of ajax.reload(), however, I ended up in a similar situation as I currently am.

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide.

**View of table and link:**

```
            <%= link_to 'Add New', new_quote_path, id: "new_link", remote: true %>




        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">       
                <div class="portlet box blue-madison">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <i class="icon-speech"></i>
                            <span class="portlet-title"><%= @quote.company_name %> Census </span>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  id="sample_2">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Subscriber ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Dob</th>
                <th>Sub status</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Uses tobacco</th>
                <th>Tobacco cessation</th>
                <th>Emp status</th>
                <th>Coverage type</th>
                <th>Currently enrolled</th>
                <th>Current anthem</th>
                <th>Current plan</th>
                <th>Premium</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <% @employees.where(:company_name => @client.company_name).each do |employee| %>
                <tr>
                  <td>                        
                    <a class="xediable-example" href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "family_id" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.family_id %> 
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>                          
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "first_name" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.first_name %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "last_name" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.last_name %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "dob" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.dob %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "sub_status" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.sub_status %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "gender" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.gender %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "uses_tobacco" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.uses_tobacco %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "tobacco_cessation" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.tobacco_cessation %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "emp_status" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.emp_status %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "coverage_type" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.coverage_type %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "currently_enrolled" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.currently_enrolled %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "current_anthem" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.current_anthem %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "current_plan_id" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.current_plan_id %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  <td>                        
                    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= employee.id %>" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name = "premium" data-url="/employees/<%= employee.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
                      <%= employee.premium %>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**#sample_2 Javascript:**

```
var initTable2 = function () {
    var table = $('#sample_2');



    /* Table tools samples: https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/ */

    /* Set tabletools buttons and button container */
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
        "container": "btn-group tabletools-dropdown-on-portlet",
        "buttons": {
            "normal": "btn btn-sm default",
            "disabled": "btn btn-sm default disabled"
        },
        "collection": {
            "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu tabletools-dropdown-menu"
        }

    var oTable = table.dataTable({
        "order": [
            [0, 'asc']
        ],

        "lengthMenu": [
            [5, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
        ],
        // set the initial value
        "pageLength": 5,

        "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // horizobtal scrollable datatable

        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [{
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sButtonText": "PDF"
            },  {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sButtonText": "Excel"
            }, {
                "sExtends": "print",
                "sButtonText": "Print",
                "sInfo": 'Please press "CTR+P" to print or "ESC" to quit',
                "sMessage": "Generated by DataTables"
            }]
        }
    });


    var tableWrapper = $('#sample_2_wrapper'); // datatable creates the table wrapper by adding with id {your_table_jd}_wrapper
    tableWrapper.find('.dataTables_length select').select2(); // initialize select2 dropdown
}
```

**Form with Javascript**

```
    <%= form_for @employee, remote: true  do |f| %>
  <% if @employee.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@employee.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this employee from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @employee.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :company_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :family_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :family_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dob %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :dob %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sub_status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :sub_status %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gender %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :gender %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :uses_tobacco %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :uses_tobacco %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tobacco_cessation %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tobacco_cessation %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :emp_status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_status %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :coverage_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :coverage_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :currently_enrolled %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :currently_enrolled %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_anthem %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :current_anthem %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_plan_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :current_plan_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :quote_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :quote_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :premium %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :premium %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $("#new_employee").submit(function(){
    $("#new_link").show();
    $("#new_employee").remove();

    $("#sample_2").DataTable().destroy();
    $("#sample_2").DataTable().draw();


  });

</script>
```

**Html Output:**

```
    <div class="page-content" style="min-height:783px"> 
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
            <h3 class="page-title">
        ABC Company <small></small>
            </h3>
            <!-- BEGIN BREADCRUMB-->
            <div class="page-bar">
                <ul class="page-breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a> </a><a href="/"><i class="icon-home"> </i> Home</a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div> 
                    <h3>Account Information </h3>
                </div>
                    <table id="user" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:15%">
                                 Company Status
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%"> 
                  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="1" data-model="client" data-type="text" data-name="company_status" data-url="/clients/1" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                     Active
                  </a>
                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:15%">
                                 Zip Code
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%"> 
                  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="1" data-model="client" data-type="text" data-name="zip_code" data-url="/clients/1" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                     04963
                  </a>
                </td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:15%">
                                 Number of Employees
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%"> 
                  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="1" data-model="client" data-type="text" data-name="number_ees" data-url="/clients/1" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                     100
                  </a>
                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:15%">
                                 Profit Center
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%"> 
                  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="1" data-model="client" data-type="text" data-name="profit_center" data-url="/clients/1" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                     Augusta BIA
                  </a>
                </td>
                        </tr>                       
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div> 
                    <h3>Benefits Team </h3>
                </div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:15%">
                                 Company Name
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%"> 
                  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="1" data-model="client" data-type="text" data-name="company_name" data-url="/clients/1" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                     ABC Company
                  </a>
                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:15%">
                                 Producer
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%"> 
                  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="1" data-model="client" data-type="text" data-name="ben_producer" data-url="/clients/1" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                     Michael
                  </a>
                </td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:15%">
                                 Account Manager
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%"> 
                  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="1" data-model="client" data-type="text" data-name="ben_manager" data-url="/clients/1" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                     Jessika
                  </a>
                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:15%">
                                 Benefits Specialist
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%"> 
                  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="1" data-model="client" data-type="text" data-name="ben_csr" data-url="/clients/1" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                     Paige
                  </a>
                </td>
                        </tr>                       
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>




            <a id="new_link" data-remote="true" href="/quotes/new" style="display: inline;">Add New</a>
<script>

  $("#new_employee").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#new_link").show();
    $("#new_employee").remove();

     $("#sample_2").DataTable().destroy();
     $("#sample_2").DataTable().draw();



  });

</script>




            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">       
                    <div class="portlet box blue-madison">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="icon-speech"></i>
                                <span class="portlet-title">ABC Company Census </span>
                            </div>



                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body">
              <div id="sample_2_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><div class="dataTables_length" id="sample_2_length"><label> <select name="sample_2_length" aria-controls="sample_2" class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline"><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> records </label></div></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><div id="sample_2_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input type="search" class="form-control input-small input-inline" aria-controls="sample_2"></label></div></div></div><div class="table-scrollable"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-footer dataTable" id="sample_2" role="grid" aria-describedby="sample_2_info">
                <thead>
                  <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Subscriber ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 90.888888835907px;" aria-sort="ascending">Subscriber ID</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="First name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 71.888888835907px;">First name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Last name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 70.888888835907px;">Last name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Dob: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 31.888888835907px;">Dob</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Sub status: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 70.888888835907px;">Sub status</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Gender: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 49.888888835907px;">Gender</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Uses tobacco: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 89.888888835907px;">Uses tobacco</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Tobacco cessation: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 122.888888835907px;">Tobacco cessation</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Emp status: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 74.888888835907px;">Emp status</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Coverage type: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 95.888888835907px;">Coverage type</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Currently enrolled: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 123.888888835907px;">Currently enrolled</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Current anthem: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 108.888888835907px;">Current anthem</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Current plan: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 85.888888835907px;">Current plan</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Premium: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 63px;">Premium</th></tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                      <td class="sorting_1">                          
                        <a class="xediable-example editable editable-click" href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="family_id" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title">
                          12 
                          </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>                          
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="first_name" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="last_name" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="dob" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click">
                          2015-03-31
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="sub_status" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="gender" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="uses_tobacco" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="tobacco_cessation" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="emp_status" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="coverage_type" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="currently_enrolled" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="current_anthem" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="current_plan_id" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                      <td>                        
                        <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="77" data-model="employee" data-type="text" data-name="premium" data-url="/employees/77" data-title="Enter title" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr></tbody>
              </table></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12"><div class="dataTables_info" id="sample_2_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries</div></div><div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12"><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="sample_2_paginate"><ul class="pagination"><li class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="sample_2" tabindex="0" id="sample_2_previous"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li><li class="paginate_button active" aria-controls="sample_2" tabindex="0"><a href="#">1</a></li><li class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="sample_2" tabindex="0" id="sample_2_next"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: It is often useful to also provide the output HTML of the page, e.g. as saved from your browser, not just the source. That way we don't need to compile everything in our heads :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still cannot find any elements with an id of `new_employee` in your samples. Also, your injected script is in the middle of the HTML, but is not wrapped in a DOM ready event handler function. Was that intentional?

Comment: The new_employee is referring to the new employee form. The event trigger and the method tied to that id, $("#new_employee").remove();, are working. The script is in the middle of the page because it is in the form file for the time being and the form is rendered mid-page. I did just wrap the script in a DOM ready event handler but that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML output, this is a bit of a guess, but you are not stopping the default submit behaviour of the form (which is to replace the page). Call `preventDefault()` on the `submit` event's first parameter.

e.g.

```
$("#new_employee").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
```

This will stop the form from actually posting back to the server when you click any submit buttons.

Comment: I tried this and it did not seem to make any difference. I did add the page-content html output, maybe that will help? Thank you for the quick response! Also, I apologize - the indentation on the html output seems to have lost some integrity in the copy/paste.